# JPA NAMED Query issue

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Getting below database excpetion, help required

```
service() for servlet catalogservice threw exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Named query not found: SELECT OMX_PLAN_ID, PLAN_ID,DECODE(plan_id,0,ser_input_total_amount,first_payment) first_paymenmt From (SELECT OMX_PLAN_ID, PLAN_ID,(SELECT DECODE(fraction,0,fixed_payment_amount, (( fraction/100) * :useinput_total_amount)) From TFN.VW_OMX_PAYMENT_PLAN_DETAILS i WHERE o.OMX_PLAN_ID=i.OMX_PLAN_ID AND i.OMX_PLAN_ID=:omxPlanId AND i.PAYMENT_ID=1) first_payment FM TFN.VW_OMX_PAYMENT_PLANS o ) WHERE OMX_PLAN_ID=:omxPlanId ORDER by 1
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createNamedQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:704) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Fin
```

### DAO Method

public TermPayment findFirstPaymentByTotalAndPlanId(int planId, double totalAmount) {

```
    TypedQuery<TermPayment> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("SELECT OMX_PLAN_ID, PLAN_ID,DECODE(plan_id,0,:user_input_total_amount,first_payment) first_paymenmt From (SELECT OMX_PLAN_ID, PLAN_ID,(SELECT DECODE(fraction,0,fixed_payment_amount, (( fraction/100) * :user_input_total_amount)) From TFN.VW_OMX_PAYMENT_PLAN_DETAILS i WHERE o.OMX_PLAN_ID=i.OMX_PLAN_ID AND i.OMX_PLAN_ID=:omxPlanId AND i.PAYMENT_ID=1) first_payment FROM TFN.VW_OMX_PAYMENT_PLANS o ) WHERE OMX_PLAN_ID=:omxPlanId ORDER by 1", TermPayment.class);
    query.setParameter("omxPlanId", planId);
    query.setParameter("user_input_total_amount", totalAmount);
    return   query.getSingleResult();
}
```

### Return class

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class TermPayment {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "OMX_PLAN_ID")   
    Integer omxPlanId;

    @Column(name = "PLAN_ID")   
    Integer planId;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_PAYMENT")
    Double firstPayment;

    public Integer getOmxPlanId() {
        return omxPlanId;
    }
    public void setOmxPlanId(Integer omxPlanId) {
        this.omxPlanId = omxPlanId;
    }
    public Integer getPlanId() {
        return planId;
    }
    public void setPlanId(Integer planId) {
        this.planId = planId;
    }
    public Double getFirstPayment() {
        return firstPayment;
    }
    public void setFirstPayment(Double firstPayment) {
        this.firstPayment = firstPayment;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the `java.persistence.EntityManager` javadoc:

```
/**
 * Create an instance of <code>Query</code> for executing a named query
 * (in the Java Persistence query language or in native SQL).
 * @param name the name of a query defined in metadata
 * @return the new query instance
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if a query has not been
 *         defined with the given name or if the query string is
 *         found to be invalid
 */
public Query createNamedQuery(String name);
```

so you should create your named query and only refer to it using `createNamedQuery`.

Comment: There are two methods Query createNamedQuery(java.lang.String name) 
          
<T> TypedQuery<T> createNamedQuery(java.lang.String name, java.lang.Class<T> resultClass)

Comment: I see, so why don't you stick to the respective javadoc? `"The select list of the query must contain only a single item, which must be assignable to the type specified by the <code>resultClass</code> argument."`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a query from a string, you can use the createQuery(String query, Class type) method.

You can replace the method used in your DAO:

```
entityManager.createNamedQuery(...)
```

For this one:

```
entityManager.createQuery("select OMX_PLAN_ID, PLAN_ID ...", TermPayment.class)
```

Alternatively, you can create a NamedQuery adding a NamedQuery annotation in your Entity class or using xml. Afterthat, you could use the NamedQuery passing the NamedQuery name to the createNamedQuery() method.

```
@NamedQuery(name="MyQuery", query="select OMX_PLAN_ID, PLAN_ID ...")

entityManager.createNamedQuery(MyQuery, TermPayment.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `NamedQuery` api for creating `dynamic queries` which is wrong.
From [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbrg.html)

`createNamedQuery method is used to create static queries, or queries that are defined in metadata by using the javax.persistence.NamedQuery annotation. The name element of @NamedQuery specifies the name of the query that will be used with the createNamedQuery method. The query element of @NamedQuery is the query:`

```
@NamedQuery(
    name="findAllCustomersWithName",
    query="SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.name LIKE :custName"
)

Here’s an example of createNamedQuery, which uses the @NamedQuery:

@PersistenceContext
public EntityManager em;
...
customers = em.createNamedQuery("findAllCustomersWithName")
    .setParameter("custName", "Smith")
    .getResultList();
```

You need to do something like,

`entityManager.createQuery(
    "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.name LIKE :custName")
    .setParameter("custName", name)`